# Overflow not containing div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

dumb question because I know I should know the answer, but I just can't think of it at the moment, so I need some help.

I have a div of fixed width and fixed height, everything is centered, it looks fancy. It's going to be a dynamic counter so I need it to only display one number on the list at time. The list items overflow from the parent container even though I have `overflow-y` set to `none`. Code is below; Can someone help me fix my overflow problem? NOTE: I am using bootstrap 3.0

HTML

```
    <div class='container'>
        <div id='odometer'>
            <div class='col-xs-3 odo'>
            <ul class='odo-number'>
                <?
                    for($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++){
                        print "<li>$i</li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3 odo'>
            <ul class='odo-number'>
                <?
                    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                        print "<li>$i</li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3 odo'>
            <ul class='odo-number'>
                <?
                    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                        print "<li>$i</li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3 odo'>
            <ul class='odo-number'>
                <?
                    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
                        print "<li>$i</li>";
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#odometer{
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 400px;
    overflow-y: none;
}
#odometer .odo{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 137px;
    overflow: none;

}
.odo-number{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    text-align : center;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;

}
.odo-number:nth-child(-n+1){
    width: 99px;
    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
.odo-number li{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 96px;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #2f2f2f), color-stop(.5, #1e1f1f), color-stop(.51, #0c0c0c), to(#000));
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

'none' is not a valid value for the overflow property.  Try changing it to:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Comment: good lord... I've gone retarded, I've been using the none keyword so much it's embedded itself. Quick fix! Thank you!

Comment: We've all been there - don't worry!

Comment: well give me 10 ten minutes and I'll accept! Thanks agian!